# Why is this sentence grammatical without 的?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading a short narrative about someone who bought a big clock, much to the surprise of his roommate. The roommate asks him: “你家里不是已经有几个钟了吗？”

I'm not exactly sure why this construction is grammatical because of the 不是. My best guess is that this is used for emphasis/rhetorical effect, but I'm not positive. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's rhetorical effect.

- 「不是」commonly means "be not", as in sentence

> 「这个苹果**不是**我的。」(This apple **is not** mine).

This type of「不是」 is considered as the opposite of 「是」.

- But in you example sentence,

> 「你家里**不是**已经有几个钟了吗？」

「不是」does not mean the opposite of 「是」. This sentence can be reworded to

> 你家里已经有几个钟了，**不是**吗？(You already have several clocks at home, don't you?)

You may consider this type of「不是」as a primitive word. It is used for emphasis/rhetorical effect as you have guessed.